# Android, Centering image in actionbar

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I have created an actionbar with below code :

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_about, null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

I just have a simple image in the actionbar which I want to be vertically centered. here's my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myImg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

There are multiple questions on this topic on StackOverflow and I tried almost all of them and none of them worked for me. The result is just my image on the left side of the actionbar.
Thanks

Comment: show your image and how it appears as of now on the actionbar

Comment: Do you want it just vertically centered or centered on the entire layout? Because if it's just vertical centering, then there doesn't seem to be a problem with your code. If you want to center it on the entire layout, try switching to a relative layout and center it in the parent. You might also want to change the height of the enclosing layout to `match_parent`.

Comment: @Virus I think it is very easy to imagine. An actionbar and an image centered vertically on it!

Comment: @AlexKombo No I just want it to be vertically centered on the actionbar

Comment: yes, i ask because the problem could be with the image itself. The margins around the main content etc.

Comment: @m0j1 Try change the `LinearLayout` height to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: @AlexKombo doing so increases the height of the actionbar and also doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `toolbar` instead. A `toolbar` is more flexible and has more functions.